# How to update the Neo4j webadmin without restarting the server?

Tags: neo4j

I have a Neo4j server running on my machine and access the database via the webadmin interface. Then I run a java application which writes data to the database using the Java API and exists afterwards.
If I then try to see the new data in the webadmin, I have to restart the Neo4j server (refreshing doesn't help).

How can I refresh the webadmin without having to restart the server?

Comment: how does your app write the data? REST? Native Java API?

Comment: I use the Java API. Added it to the original question.